# same data is showing two times after adding into list while save changes -react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a list('Configured items') with retrieved items of last saved changes. Those items are stored in jobdetailjson. Now, I have another list 'New item' having various items and add button with each item of that list. Now problem is - if I add any item from 'New item' list to 'Configured items' list concat with last retrieved item and save the changes. It is saving but it is showing last added item two times. How to restrict that?

I am using reducer function to add New item to the Configured item list. Is it a global state problem? Here is my code:

action for add item:

```
export const addLocation = mruCode =>({
  type: ADD_LOCATION,
  payload:mruCode
});
```

reducer for add item:

```
case 'ADD_LOCATION':
         let addedLoc = state.location.find(obj=>(obj.mruCode === action.payload))
               return{
                   ...state,
                   conLocations: [...state.conLocations,addedLoc]
               };
```

Component code (getLocationData is the function which is concatenating redux state item and local state retrieved item)

```
export class NewLocationPanel extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
               open:false,
               configuredList:[],
               clearList:[]
        };
       this.configLocation = this.configLocation.bind(this);
        this.togglePanel = this.togglePanel.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.allLocations = this.allLocations.bind(this);
        this.clearall = this.clearall.bind(this);
        this.getLocationData = this.getLocationData.bind(this);
        this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
        this.removeConfigLocation = this.removeConfigLocation.bind(this);
        this.removeLocationAll = this.removeLocationAll.bind(this);
    }

    togglePanel (e){
        this.setState({open : !this.state.open});
    }
    handleRemove(mruCode){
        this.props.removeLocation(mruCode)
     }
    handleClick (mruCode){
      this.props.addLocation(mruCode)
     }
     allLocations (){
       this.props.addAllLocation()
    }
    clearall (){
        this.props.removeAllLocation()
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.loadData();
      }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
        if ((prevProps.jobId != this.props.jobId || prevProps.jobDetailJson != this.props.jobDetailJson) && this.props.jobDetailJson != undefined) {
            this.configLocation(this.props.jobDetailJson);
        }

    }

    configLocation(jobDetailJson){
        let configuredList = jobDetailJson.locations.locationDetails;
        this.setState({configuredList});
    }

    removeConfigLocation(index){
        this.setState(({configuredList})=>{
            let remList = [...configuredList]
            remList.splice(index,1)
            return {
                configuredList:remList
            }
        })
    }

    removeLocationAll(){
        if(this.props.jobDetailJson != null){
         let configuredList = this.props.jobDetailJson.locations.locationDetails;
               this.setState({configuredList:[]});
        }
    }

    getLocationData(){
         let saveableLocationlist = [];
         if(this.props.conLocations != null && this.props.conLocations!=undefined && this.props.jobDetailJson !=null && this.props.jobDetailJson !=undefined){
             let confLocationList = this.props.conLocations;
             let retrievedList = this.props.jobDetailJson.locations.locationDetails;
            let totalList = retrievedList.filter(loc=> !confLocationList.some(newLoc => newLoc.mruCode===loc.mruCode));
            saveableLocationlist = totalList.concat(confLocationList);
         }
         else if(this.props.jobDetailJson === null && this.props.conLocations != null){
             let confListNewJob = this.props.conLocations;
             saveableLocationlist = confListNewJob;
         }
        const locationData = {
            locationDetails : saveableLocationlist
        }
      return locationData;
    }

    render(){
        //const{configuredList} = this.state;
        const _labels = store.getLabels();
        let collapsedToggle = this.props.open ? 'collapsed' : ''
        return(
            <div className="panel panel-default">
            <div className="panel-heading" onClick={(e)=>this.togglePanel(e)}>
              <div className="row">
              <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-6 panelHeadingLabel">
                     <span>{this.props.title}</span>
                     </div>
                        <div className="pull-right">
                        <span className="defaultHeaderTextColor">{this.state.configuredList.map((loc,index)=><span key={index}>{loc.mruCode} - {_labels[loc.division]} - {loc.country}</span>)}
                           <span onClick={(e)=>this.togglePanel(e)} className={this.state.open ? "collapse-chevronn" : "collapse-chevron"} aria-hidden="true"></span>
                   </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
              {this.state.open?(
                        <div className="panel-body">
                             <div className="row grid-divider">
                             <div className="col-sm-6">
                             <div className="col-padding"><div className="pos-div"><h3>Locations List</h3><button style={{ display: this.props.location.length === this.props.conLocations.length ? "none" : "block" }} className="allLargeBtn" onClick={()=>{this.allLocations()}}>Add all locations</button></div><hr/>
                             {this.props.location.map((item,index)=>(
                             <div key={index}><div><b>{item.mruCode} - {_labels[item.division]} - {item.country}</b>{!this.props.conLocations.find(item2 => item.mruCode === item2.mruCode)&&(<div className="pull-right jd"><button style={{ display: this.state.configuredList.find(item3=> item.mruCode===item3.mruCode) ? "none" : "block" }} className="call-to-action" onClick={()=>{this.handleClick(item.mruCode)}}>Add Location</button></div>)}<hr/></div></div>))}
                            </div>
                             </div> 
                                  <div className="col-sm-6">
                                  <div className="col-padding">
                                  <div className="pos-div"><h3>Configured Location</h3><button className="allLargeBtn" onClick={()=>this.clearall()}>Remove all location</button></div><hr/>
              <div><table className="table"><thead>{this.state.configuredList.map((locc,index)=><tr key={index}><th><b>{locc.mruCode} - {_labels[locc.division]} - {locc.country}</b></th><th className="text-right"><img alt="DeleteIcon" onClick={()=>{this.removeConfigLocation(index)}} className="deleteIconStyle" src="img/delete_large_active.png" /></th></tr>)}</thead><tbody>
                        {this.props.conLocations.map((loct,index)=><tr key={index}>
                           <td><b>{loct.mruCode} - {_labels[loct.division]} - {loct.country}</b></td>
                           <td className="text-right"><img alt="DeleteIcon" onClick={()=>this.handleRemove(loct.mruCode)}className="deleteIconStyle" src="img/delete_large_active.png" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        )}
                    </tbody></table></div>

                                   </div>
                                  </div>
                                  </div> 
                    </div>):null}
            </div>

        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
    return{
        location:state.locationRed.location,
        conLocations:state.locationRed.conLocations
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return{
        loadData:()=>{dispatch(loadData())},
        addLocation:(mruCode)=>{dispatch(addLocation(mruCode))},
        addAllLocation:() =>{dispatch(addAllLocation())},
        removeLocation: (mruCode)=>{dispatch(removeLocation(mruCode))},
        removeAllLocation: () =>{dispatch(removeAllLocation())}
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps,null,{withRef:true})(NewLocationPanel);
```

Jobspanel( where i am saving the changes)

```
class JobsPanelComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            jobDetailJson: this.props.jobDetailJson

        };
this.setLocationPanelRef = cRef =>{this.locationPanel = cRef;};

}
componentWillUnmount() {
        this.clearStates();
        this.clearRefs();
        this.clearBindings();
    }
          clearStates() {

        this.state.jobDetailJson = null;
        }
        clearRefs(){
               this.locationPanel = null;
                   }
        clearBindings(){
               this.setLocationPanelRef = null;
                       }
        componentWillMount() {
        this.state.jobDetailJson = this.props.jobDetailJson;
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.state.jobDetailJson = nextProps.jobDetailJson;
    }
      render(){
         var locationDataJson= null;
             if(this.state.jobDetailJson != null){
                     locationDataJson =this.state.jobDetailJson.locations;
                   }
         return(<div className="panel-group" id="jobsPanelGroup">
               class JobsPanelComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            jobDetailJson: this.props.jobDetailJson

        };
this.setLocationPanelRef = cRef =>{this.locationPanel = cRef;};

}
componentWillUnmount() {
        this.clearStates();
        this.clearRefs();
        this.clearBindings();
    }
          clearStates() {

        this.state.jobDetailJson = null;
        }
        clearRefs(){
               this.locationPanel = null;
                   }
        clearBindings(){
               this.setLocationPanelRef = null;
                       }
        componentWillMount() {
        this.state.jobDetailJson = this.props.jobDetailJson;
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.state.jobDetailJson = nextProps.jobDetailJson;
    }
     saveJobData(jobdata){
        if(this.locationPanel!=undefined{
        let locationData = this.locationPanel.getWrappedInstance().getLocationData();
       }
       }
      render(){
         var locationDataJson= null;
             if(this.state.jobDetailJson != null){
                     locationDataJson =this.state.jobDetailJson.locations;
                   }
         return(<div className="panel-group" id="jobsPanelGroup">
               <LocationPanel ref={this.setLocationPanelRef} locationData ={locationDataJson} jobDetailJson={this.state.jobDetailJson} versionId={versionId} jobName={jobName} jobId={jobId} isForViewOnly={this.props.isForViewOnly} title="Location"/></div>
              );
         }


}
              );
         }


}
```

I am adding the output screenshot:(problem)
[image: last item added two times]

'1000' is the retrieved item. I have added '7300' with this. but it is showing two times.

Comment: create codesandbox example

Answer (score 0):

When click to add a location, in reducer, add the selected location to conLocations. I think later, the trigger the `componentDidUpdate` method, add the location again.

Comment: I checked all codes, your configuredList was jobDetailJson.locations.locationDetails. It is from props. But there was no logic to change the jobDetailJson in your code when add a location.

Comment: i have added component from where i am calling jobdetailjson. How to change jobDetailjson? Now, it is saving properly but it is loading two times .If problem is in componentDidUpdate then how to resist that?